# POWER QUERY [Expression.Error] Cannot convert the value null to type Table

Tags: apply, powerquery, m

**SOLVED USING A DIFFERENT APPROACH (see at the end)**

I am trying to combine some queries into one by using the Table.Combine() function.

If I explicitly write the name of each query (e. g., Table.Combine({#"Name of query 1", #"Name of query 2"})) and then apply the changes, everything works fine.

However, since I want to make it dynamic, instead of writing a list of names, I pass the function a list of tables generated in a previous step:

[image: [ALT TEXT: screenshot of a table of two columns ("Name" and "Value"), with four records. "Name": COMPRAS Y GASTOS 2019... until COMPRAS Y GASTOS 2022. "Value": an object of type Table in each of the four cells].]

So after I get this table, the next step is: = Table.Combine(PreviousStep[Value]). Note that Value is the name of the column that contains the tables. Apparently, by doing so this column of a table containing tables is converted to a list containing tables. This works fine (I can preview the resultset) until I hit that Apply changes button. When I do it, this message pops up:

[image: [ALT TEXT & translation: Error pop-up message: "Load. Anexar1 (which is the name of the query): OLE DB or ODBC error: [Expression.Error] Cannot convert the value null to type Table"].]

I had a look at these threads: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/We-cannot-convert-the-value-null-to-type-Table/td-p/391064, https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/We-cannot-convert-the-value-null-to-type-table/m-p/346056, but it didn't work. I've tried other approaches as well.

Further information:

- Power BI Desktop version: 2.106.582.0 64-bit (June 2022)
- Data source: combining existing queries that come from a single Excel file.
- Steps followed to get that list of tables that I pass the Table.Combine() function:

```
    let
    Origen = #sections[Section1],
    #"Convertido en tabla" = Record.ToTable(Origen),
    #"Errores quitados" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Convertido en tabla", {"Value"}),
    Personalizado1 = Table.SelectRows(#"Errores quitados", each Text.StartsWith([Name], "COMPRAS Y GASTOS")),
    Personalizado2 = Table.Combine(Personalizado1[Value])
    in
    Personalizado2
```

I access all the queries I have (with the #sections keyword), convert it to a table, remove possible errors, filter to get the queries I want (the ones starting by "COMPRAS Y GASTOS") and then try to combine the queries).

**A DIFFERENT APPROACH**
What I wanted to do was merge tables that came from an Excel file, each of them referring to a year (2019, 2020, 2021, 2022). But I also wanted the combined table to update when new sheets were added on Excel (2023, 2024...).

I've tried many different approaches, like generating a dynamic list (from 2019 until the *current year*)... but for some reason none of them worked, even though the code apparently is correct.

So my new approach has been to create a sufficient amount of Excel sheets for the coming years (that are now empty, but when the new year comes the information will be filled in there), to create the queries referring to those sheets (they return empty tables) and merging those existing (but empty) tables with the ones from 2019-2022. This way, when data from 2023 is filled in in the sheet, the query is updated and it works.

It's a shame I couldn't actually solve the original problem I had, but this approach works.

Comment: your code as written works perfectly for me, so it is a puzzlement

Comment: Yea... What version of Power BI do you have? Does it matter at all? (I don't think so, but). Also, can you think of any way to work around my problem? Table.Combine({explicit, list, of, the, names, of, the, queries}) works fine, but apparently it doesn't when I pass the arguments as "parameters" (results from other queries).

Comment: I also generated in a query that string of arguments (result = {explicit, list, of, the, names, of, the, queries}), and tried Table.Combine(result), but errors like "can't convert "explicit" to type Table arise...

Comment: Can you please provide a copy of the source data and the code to re-generate it? So that way we can try to reproduce it? You can follow the instructions here: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)